# How To Always Hide UISplitViewController Details View Controller

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller

Is there anyway to hide the details view controller of a UISplitviewController in all circumstances? I have this requirement where the details VC needs to be hidden (or absent) at first and then slide in from the right when an initial selection is made. This needs to be the case even when a large iPad is in full screen mode.

I know I can simply create my own version of this using a view controller with two child view controllers embed and manipulating constraints, however then I lose the push and pop functionally that you automatically get when in a compact size class.